# After upgrading to ubuntu 15.04 compiz slows the system down

Tags: ati, compiz, dell, intel, 15.04

I just upgraded to ubuntu 15.04, and not only was dual monitor capability lost, but compiz seemed to make the CPU run at 80% despite there was nothing running. I installed the compiz editor and tried some things, but can't figure out what's wrong.

Specs:
 Dell Optiplex GX 755
 4 Gbs DDR3 RAM
 Intel Core 2 Duo Processor @2.66 GhZ
 ATI Radeon HD 3470 256MB PCI Express x16 S-Video/ DMS-59 V

Comment: I've experienced a similar problem with 14.04 as well, and read somewhere on the web that this was due compiz copying the whole screen buffer to redraw even a small thing -- like a blinking cursor. Since I have a 4K monitor plus a 1600x1200 monitor, this was very significant. I ended up switching to Xfce.